# VS2019 - Insert New Line for object, collections and array initializers not working

Tags: c#, settings, visual-studio-2019

The insert New Line setting in VS2019 does not seem to work for object, collections and array initializers. It works in all other cases, but for these types it does not work, for example:

```
// result:
int i = new int[] {};

// expected:
int i = new int[]
{
    <cursor here>
};
```

What I tried:

`Text editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > New Lines`

*Checked all the options for new line.*

`Resharper`

*Set all possible new line options to BSD Style (insert new line).*

`.editorconfig`

*Auto-generated this file to attempt to override another one somewhere (if any).
`csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = all` was set in there.*

None of the above worked. I disabled IntelliCode extension and removed the .editorconfig, restarted VS, no luck. These solutions seem to work in some cases but not in my setup. Note that I disabled automatic brace completion/closing.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Try unticking the following checkbox `ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Line Breaks and Wrapping | Arrangement of Initializers | Place simple array, object, and collection on a single line`.

Comment: @AlexanderKurakin With this and (maybe) what I tried before it now seems better indeed, but there are so many combinations of settings that it's hard to say which setting is making the difference. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I may need to confirm something with you, do you mean when you press “enter” in braces, and the result will like this

```
int[] i = new int[] {

};
```

instead of formatting like expected? Feel free to let me know if I misunderstand you.

**Suggestions**

If yes, based on my test, please kindly check again if you have select this option: “Place open brace on new line for object, collection and array initializers” from Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > New Lines > “Place open brace on new line for object, collection and array initializers”.

[image]

In addition, [reset Visual Studio settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2019#reset-settings) will fix this issue and make settings to default, you could consider and try this if you didn’t change or customize some other settings in VS. (Tools > Import and Export Settings… > Reset all settings > choose “No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings” > General > Finish)

Comment: As I said, all the checkboxes are checked in there. On another machine, however, the close brace is automatically inserted unlike on this one. Cursor is between the braces and when I hit enter, I get the expected result, so maybe it's linked to that.